# Xcode analyzer ignores autorelease

Tags: xcode, memory, memory-leaks, autorelease, analyzer

I am using latest Xcode, and trying to find memory leaks.
When i use 'Analyze'
It shows following as potential leak:

```
+ (UITableViewCell *) method {
UITableViewCell *cell = [[TestX alloc]init];
... do some stuff
return [cell autorelease];
}
```

Should i just ignore it ?

Comment: This is a sample code, how to release 'Cell' object ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you shouldn't ignore warnings.  Sometimes Xcode is buggy and forgets you've changed the code.  Try restarting Xcode.  Remove *do some stuff* so that it's just the two lines and see if the analyser stops warning you.  It could be the case that you're affecting the retain count in that code somewhere without realising it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to name the method properly to show that it's returning an autoreleased object.  I forget the preferred name.  Try something like 'newObject'.

Comment: No, that's the exact opposite of what he should do.  A method name with `new` in it indicates that the method passes ownership back, i.e. that it's *not* autoreleased.